# In TFS 2015, how do I block contributors from checking into a branch while allowing the project administrators branch?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, tfs-2015, tfvc

I'm working with TFS 2015 using the [ALM Rangers Development & Release Isolation Branching Strategy](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) and Team Foundation Version Control. I would like to keep developers from checking code into the Main branch and letting them only work in Dev and Release branches. I want to allow the Project Administrators and above to perform the merges and check ins to Main.

With Team Web Access:

- I selected the drop-down next to my Main branch and selected
  "Security".
- Set Inheritance to "Off".
- For Contributors, Set Check in and a few other permissions to "Deny".
- Saved Changes.
- For Project Administrators, set the same permissions to "Allow"
- Saved Changes.
- TFS changed the values of each of the Project Administrators permissions to "Inherited deny*"

I have heard that setting "deny" can cause problems. Now I understand why I was told that. Is there a way to achieve my stated goal above, through standard TFS permission settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cann’t  reproduce your problem with the same settings in my TFS2015.

According to TFS permission setting, most groups and almost all permissions, **Deny** trumps **Allow**. If a user belongs to two groups, and one of them has a specific permission set to Deny, that user will not be able to perform tasks that require that permission even if they belong to a group that has that permission set to Allow.

To achieve what you want, you can **create a new group** such as DenyMainGroup.  Adding the developers to this group. Make sure your project administrator members don’t belong to it.  For this group, set Check in and a few other permissions to “Deny”. For **Contributors** and **Project Administrators**, set the same permissions to”Allow”. Saved Changes.